# JavaScript; Background Color change and change back w/ same input

Tags: javascript, css, html

I made this code, but it wont work. Would be nice if some one can help me. :)

I've tried many things already, but it always didn't worked.

I want it to be so that you press the button and the background gets light, when you press it again it goes back to the origin.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
    .darkerBG {
        background: #282828;
    }
    .lighterBG {
        background: white;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="darkerBG" id="bdbackground">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changeColor() 
{
    var bdBackground = document.getElementById('bdbackground').class;

    if (document.getElementById('bdbackground').class == 'darkerBG')
    {
        document.getElementById('bdbackground').class == 'lighterBG';
    } else if (document.getElementById('bdbackground').class == 'lighterBG')
    {
        document.getElementById('bdbackground').class = 'darkerBG';
    }
}
</script>

<input type="button" class="button" value="test" onclick="changeColor()">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the correct property is `.className` instead of `.class`. You also have an erroneous `==` in your assignment of `document.getElementById('bdbackground').class == 'lighterBG';`

Alternatively, consider using `.classList.contains(...)`.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
 <style>
 .darkerBG {
 background: #282828;
 }
 .lighterBG {
 background: white;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body class="darkerBG" id="bdbackground">

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function changeColor() {
  var myElement = document.getElementById('bdbackground');
  if (myElement.className == 'darkerBG') {
   myElement.className = 'lighterBG';
  } else if (myElement.className == 'lighterBG') {
   myElement.className = 'darkerBG';
  }
 }
 </script>
 
<input type="button" class="button" value="test" onclick="changeColor()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now it changes to white, but when I press the button again, it wont go back to the original color

Answer (score 3):

You must use `className` rather than `class`. `class` is not a property [on a DOM element](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the `className` property on the element rather than `class`.

For example:

```
document.getElementById('bdbackground').className = 'darkerBG';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a working solution for what you are trying to achieve. I created a JSBin with the solution and improved your code slightly: http://jsbin.com/botasehoci/1/edit?html,css,js,output

(Edit, just noticed Quantastical answered with pretty much all the issues I brought up in the time it took me to to post this answer :/ )

The main issues were that:

- You needed to include the ID `bdbackground` on the button element.
- You needed to include the initial class name on the button element ("lighterBG")
- The correct way to reference the value of the class attribute is using `className` not `class`
- For the first condition in the if statement, you used an comparison instead of an assignment operator ( i.e. `x == a` instead of `x = a` )

This is the updated JS:

```
function changeColor() {
    var button = document.getElementById('bdbackground');
    var buttonClass = button.className;

    if (buttonClass === 'darkerBG') {
        button.className = 'lighterBG';
    } else if (buttonClass === 'lighterBG') {
        button.className = 'darkerBG';
    }
}
```

This is the updated HTML for the button element:

```
 <input id="bdbackground" type="button" class="lighterBG" value="test" onclick="changeColor()">
```

Answer (score 1):

> **[.classList()](http://callmenick.com/post/add-remove-classes-with-javascript-property-classlist)**

Use `.classList.add()` and `.classList.remove()` to toggle classes.  You could use `.classList.toggle()` but in certain circumstances the toggled states will get discombobulated if there is more than one toggler used at the same time.

#### Basic Flow

When the function `changeColor()` is called:

1. Get a reference to the body with `getElementById()`
2. Find out if the body has a class called `.darkerBG` by using `.classList.contains()`
3. If it does have `.darkerBG` as a class:

   - Remove the class and ...
   - add the class `.lighterBG`
4. Otherwise:

   - Remove the class `.lighterBG` and ...
   - add the class `.darkerBG`

#### SNIPPET

```js
function changeColor() {

  var bG = document.getElementById('bdbackground');

  if (bG.classList.contains('darkerBG')) {

    bG.classList.remove('darkerBG');

    bG.classList.add('lighterBG');

  } else {
    bG.classList.add('darkerBG');

    bG.classList.remove('lighterBG');
  }
}
```

```css
.darkerBG {
  background: rgba(20, 10, 20, .6);
  transition: all 2s;
}
.lighterBG {
  background: rgba(200, 100, 200, .6);
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>

</head>

<body class="darkerBG" id="bdbackground">




  <input type="button" class="button" value="test" onclick="changeColor()">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `class` you can use [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) or [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with `add()`/ `remove()` or `toggle()`.

To check if class exists or not, you can get element attribute (class) by [`getAttribute('class')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) , then search in it using [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) by your class string.

For best practice try to avoid inline events and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/5m5ck1fk

```js
//btn = document.querySelector('.button');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0],
    bdBackground = document.getElementById('bdbackground');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  changeColor();
});

function changeColor() {
  if (bdBackground.getAttribute('class').indexOf('darkerBG') != -1) {
    bdBackground.classList.remove('darkerBG');
    bdBackground.classList.add('lighterBG');
  } else if (bdBackground.getAttribute('class').indexOf('lighterBG') != -1) {
    bdBackground.classList.remove('lighterBG');
    bdBackground.classList.add('darkerBG');
  }
}
```

```css
.darkerBG {
  background: #282828;
}
.lighterBG {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<body class="darkerBG" id="bdbackground">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="test">
</body>
```